# Visual total not matching sum of individual rows when filtering

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new in DAX and I have a report that includes sales codes and I need my visuals to show the distinct count of the sales codes. I used to filter by month and then realized than in the distinct count formula I need to force a row by row context, as whenever I applied the month filter the visual distinct count total didn´t match the row by row sum.

I applied this formula and when filtering by month, the row by row sum was equal to the distinct count total:

```
SumX Measure = 
SUMX(
    VALUES( 'Dates Table'[YearMonthnumber] ),
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT( '2020'[Sales Code] )
    )
```

However, now I need to use other filters rather than only the month, but when I filter according to  other variables, again I have the problem that the distinct count total is not matching the row by row sum. I need the visual to have the correct distinct count total (matching with the row by row sum) by selecting different filters.

I just want the distinct count to be correct according to the filters I select, there are four filters from the same table (product, country, company, customer ID) and one filter from a dates table. I attach an example so you can better understand what I need to do, my file includes the filters I usually apply and other dax formulas I have tried: [Power Bi Example](https://entregasec-my.sharepoint.com/personal/jlopez_entregas_ec/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=%2Fpersonal%2Fjlopez%5Fentregas%5Fec%2FDocuments%2FCarpetas%20Departamentales%20%2D%20JLOPEZ%2FOTROS%2FBORRADORES%2FDistinct%20Count%20Error%2Epbix&parent=%2Fpersonal%2Fjlopez%5Fentregas%5Fec%2FDocuments%2FCarpetas%20Departamentales%20%2D%20JLOPEZ%2FOTROS%2FBORRADORES&originalPath=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbnRyZWdhc2VjLW15LnNoYXJlcG9pbnQuY29tLzp1Oi9nL3BlcnNvbmFsL2psb3Blel9lbnRyZWdhc19lYy9FWjhKY1VKcEZWSktrOWpocmZUMU5pRUJ2Ti1VcHFGU29TQ3p0MVp5M2lQR3NBP3J0aW1lPUlxeG44YU11MkVn)

Thank you for any help or advice provided.

Best,
JLV

Comment: Your example link required sign in to access. Can you available it through a public google drive link?

Comment: thanks for sharing the file. As a do not have any data level idea, its difficult to understand everything. The best option is to replicate the problem with minimum data and presentation. Just keep one single slicer and presentation so that everything becomes easier to understand.